# I have made a jobs variable config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword file but when i run pipeline I get the following error ""

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

```
before_script:
  - echo "$ENV_CONTENT" >> .env

stages:
  - build
  - prod_deployment

Variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest 
  TAG_COMMIT: CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  ENV_CONTENT: $prodenv
  DOCKER DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

build:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:19.03.0-dind
  script:
    - docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD-TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST
prod_deployment:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: prod_deployment
  tags:
    - prod_deployment
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh -i ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
    - ssh -i ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker container rm -f laravel_cicd || true"
    - ssh -i ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name laravel_cicd $TAG_COMMIT"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
```

I am trying to run my pipeline but it is failing again and again and I get an error

> jobs variables config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword

Can someone guide what should I add into it? so my pipeline starts building.

This is a php laravel app

Answer (score 2):

Key names are case sensitive: `Variables:` should be `variables:`, otherwise GitLab thinks you're trying to define a job named `Variables` and fails because it's missing a required job keyword.

I got the same error when using `defaults:` instead of `default:`, the wording of the message could definitely be improved.